# How can I import my Firefox 60.x profile data into Firefox 68?

Tags: firefox, import, firefox-profile

My Linux distribution recently upgraded my Firefox version from 60.8 ESR to 68.0.2 . That's fine, I guess, but - it turns out FF 68 will not use my existing FF profile!

How can I either import my old FF's profile data into a new FF profile, or just make FF 68 use the existing profile?

In case it matters: It's Devuan 3 Beowulf (i.e. Debian 10 Buster without systemd), 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/recover-user-data-missing-after-firefox-update) explains what you need to do.

In short:

- Since Firefox 67, the default behavior is to create a new profile when you install a new version.
- You can view all profiles by browsing "about:profile" in the URL line.
- You should be able to set your old profile to be used again by default. But - a (re)start of the browser may be required.

Comment: @dsstorefile1: Ok, edited.